How to add suppression list to azure domain using nodejs sdk?
In my application i have to add suppression list on the domain using nodejs sdk
And i was following this documentation but now i stumbled upon the issue is this documentation is not upto date.
MS Azure official documentation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/manage-suppression-list-management-sdks?pivots=programming-language-javascript
I am already following exact steps
there is no suppressionLists on client instance
I need to find the solution using api do someone know how to use spi to create the same request
Things i have already tried

I have tried downgrading the sdk version but does not help
I have tried finding api for this request
Asked chatgpt but it is also helucinating

I have tried asking technical help from azure but cannot i do not have extra credit already downvoted and informed the azure team that this documentation is not update but it will take time i need something quick.

Please share the code which you have tried.

@Dharmendra Soni Could you provide more details about what kind of suppression list you're trying to create? Is it for blocking specific email addresses, domains, or something else
